# How to use lambda expression to call the comparator?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I am doing the leetcode's largest Number problem. Here is the problem:

Given a list of non negative integers, arrange them such that they form the largest number.

For example, given [3, 30, 34, 5, 9], the largest formed number is 9534330.

and there is a 5 lines C# code:

```
internal static string LargestNumber(List<int> vals)
    {
        if(vals==null || vals.Count==0)
            return "";
        vals.Sort((a,b)=>String.Compare(b+""+a,a+""+b));
        return vals[0]==0?"0":String.Join("",vals);
    }
```

it uses the lambda expression. 
But when I tried to write the java code:

```
public String largestNumber(int[] num) {
  String[] sNum = new String[num.length];
    for(int i = 0;i<num.length; i++){
        sNum[i] = Integer.toString(num[i]);
    }
    Collections.sort(sNum,(String n1,String n2) -> (n1 + n2).compareTo(n2 + n1));
    String s = sNum[0];
    for(int i = 1;i<sNum.length;i++)
        s += sNum[i];
    if(s.charAt(0) == '0')
        s = "0";
    return s;
}
```

it reports the error:
Multiple markers at this line
    - Type mismatch: cannot convert from Comparator to Comparator
    - The method sort(List, Comparator) in the type Collections is not applicable for the 
     arguments (String[], (String n1, String n2) -> {})

could anyone help me about this lambda expression problem in java?

Comment: I'm sorry, the 6th line of the second should be: Collections.sort(sNum,(String n1,String n2) -> (n1 + n2).compareTo(n2 + n1)); But it still has the same error.

Comment: You can edit your question.

Comment: String order (dictionary order) will not help you here, cause it'll return `[9, 5, 34, 30, 3]` while what you need is: `[9, 5, 34, 3, 30]`

Comment: @alfasin yeah the most important part of this problem is override the compareTo method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, you can’t sort `int`s as `String`s without an explicit conversion, however, it’s still possible to do it in one operation:

```
public String largestNumber(int[] num) {
    String s=Arrays.stream(num).mapToObj(Integer::toString)
                   .sorted((n1, n2) -> (n2+n1).compareTo(n1+n2))
                   .collect(Collectors.joining());
    return s.charAt(0) == '0'? "0": s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort array and not a collection

```
    public String largestNumber(int[] num) {

      String[] sNum = new String[num.length];

        for(int i = 0;i<num.length; i++){
            sNum[i] = Integer.toString(num[i]);
        }
        Arrays.sort(sNum,(n1, n2) -> (n1 + n2).compareTo(n2 + n1));
        String s = sNum[0];
        for(int i = 1;i<sNum.length;i++)
            s += sNum[i];
        if(s.charAt(0) == '0')
            s = "0";
        return s;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, it works, thanks a lot! could you please briefly tell me what's the difference between Collections.sort() and Arrays.sort()?

Comment: Arrays.* operate on java arrays, when "Collections.*" on java collections (some other data structures) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html

Comment: In this condition I shall use Arrays.sort() because collections.sort() sorts a list. I've got that, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Arrays.sort(sNum, (a,b)-> (b+a).compareTo(a+b));

    return String.join("", sNum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using *Java 8* you can do (almost) the same:

```
public static void largestNumber(int[] nums) {
    // move int[] to Object[]
    Object[] arr = Arrays.stream(nums)
                            .mapToObj(x -> Integer.toString(x))
                            .toArray();

    //sort by dictionary order
    Arrays.sort(arr);

    // reverse from ascending to descending order
    Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(arr));

    // back to String and print
    System.out.println(Arrays.stream(arr)
                                .reduce((x, y) -> x.toString() + y.toString())
                                .get());
}
```

That said, my comment above still stands:

> String order (dictionary order) will not help you here, cause it'll
>   return [9, 5, 34, 30, 3] while what you want is: [9, 5, 34, 3, 30]

Comment: It seems that you tried to operate nums directly, not invert it to String. But if I write like: Arrays.sort(num, (n1,n2) -> (n2 +""+ n1).compareTo(n1 +"" +n2)); it would generate a error:The method sort(int[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (int[], (<no type> n1, <no type> n2) -> 
 {})

Comment: @XiaoyuYuan "It seems that you tried to operate nums directly, not invert it to String" - do you see the line below the comment: "// move int[] to Object[]" ? this line turn the ints into objects, which will, on the next line, be sorted by `Array.sort()` as Strings.

Comment: You cannot convert int to String and compare them in one line? Because I saw a C# code vals.Sort((a,b)=>String.Compare(b+""+a,a+""+b)); which vals is a List<int>.

Comment: In this an attempt to use as many different APIs as possible? By letting the stream return an appropriately typed array, you could simply use `Arrays.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder())` instead of sorting and reversing, but you could just call `.sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())` directly on the `Stream` without needing a temporary array at all, and using `.collect(Collectors.joining())` is not only shorter than `.reduce((x, y) -> x.toString() + y.toString()).get()` but likely to be faster.

Comment: @Xiaoyu Yuan: If the source is a `List`, you *can* do a `list.sort((a,b)->(b+""+a).compareTo(a+""+b))` but, besides the fact that this is very inefficient (in C# as well), you can’t have a `List<int>` in Java due to the clear distinction between primitive data and objects. That’s also the reason why it doesn’t work for `int[]` arrays, there is no `sort` method accepting `int[]` and a `Comparator`. Nevertheless, [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30862943/2711488) shows you that you can do the same with quite concise and even efficient code.

Comment: @Holger I wasn't aware of `Comparator.reverseOrder()` - thanks! That's what I love about SO - you learn even more by answering questions :)

Comment: Note that `Comparator.reverseOrder()` has a predecessor, `Collections.reverseOrder()` which even exists since Java 1.2. But now that `interface`s can have `static` methods, `Comparator.reverseOrder()` is the place where you would look first. Both methods are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

If [`String#compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) is fine for you, then you could really simplify things a bit, and do it with a single [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) chain:

```
public static String largestNumber(int[] nums) {
    return IntStream.of(nums)
                .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
                .sorted((a, b) -> b.compareTo(a))
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Comment: In this problem we need to override the compareTo method, which is (n2 + n1).compareTo(n1 + n2), not the default one.